# Number of Or's based on a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm working on something that queries a database depending on values the user inputs.
For instance, the user can search for a country (perhaps 'Au') and any countries containing 'Au' will get returned.

The issue is that I need to be able to add a bunch of 'or' statements to a Predicate to achieve this result, but have no idea how to go about it.

Right now, I have

```
List<int> ids;
ids = (from d in DTDC.Countries
       where d.Name.ToLower().Contains( country.ToLower() )
       select d.CountryID).ToList();

var SearchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<DLC>();

// Example
searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(c => c.CountryID == 0 || c.CountryID == 1 );
```

So I need to generate

```
searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(c => c.CountryID == 0 || c.CountryID == 1 );
```

this statement depending on the values in the List that is returned from my LINQ query.

For instance, if the list has the values 0, 1, 7, then the query needs to be

```
searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(c => c.CountryID == 0 || c.CountryID == 1 || || c.CountryID == 7 );
```

Hopefully thats clear enough for someone to understand what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a full implementation of `In` method. You can choose a few of them.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T val, params T[] values)
    {
        return val.In(EqualityComparer<T>.Default, values);
    }

    public static bool In<T>(this T val, EqualityComparer<T> comparer, params T[] values)
    {
        foreach (var v in values)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(val, v)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool In<T>(this T val, Func<T, T, bool> comparer, params T[] values)
    {
        foreach (var v in values)
        {
            if (comparer(v, val)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int num = 1;
bool exist = num.In(2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: That 's true if only author wants to load all countries with thier names from the server first. But this is not mentioned by the author, i suppose. ;)

Comment: It's already being loaded from the database with the .ToList()

Comment: I need the results of my initial query to go into another one, so I don't see how this is suitable?

Comment: @Wraiyth: To answer your question: `searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(c => c.CountryID.In(0,1,2,3));`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do here.. If the list has 3 elements, do you want to generate `c => c.CountryID == 0 || c.CountryID == 1 || c.CountryID == 2`?

If so, why not just (c.CountryID < ids.Count)?

Also, if you execute a query that only returns 1 country, are you sure you want to filter it on countryID == 0?

Comment: Because the numbers aren't necessarily sequential. For instance, the IDs returned returned could be IDs 0 and 17, which means it needs to be
    c => c.CountryID == 0 || c.CountryID == 17 

I've also got something separate to handle a single ID. The solution I'm looking for here is for multiple.

Comment: Ok, I misread your post when you said it depended on the size of the list. Are you wanting to filter where c.CountryID is found on one of the countries returned in ids?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So the list could contain the values 0, 1, 5, 10, and I need *all* those included in my statement. And as far as I'm away, they all need to be in an individual predicate, I can't add one for each ID (at least, I tried it and it did not work)

Comment: I changed the PredicateBuilder to be False rather than True, and used Or's for these. However the PredicateBuilder documentation is pretty  unclear on whether its safe to be using 'And'. The posts and examples I've seen all seem to enforce

    var SearchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<DLC>();
    SearchPredicate = SearchPredicate.Or( something );

or

    var SearchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<DLC>();
    SearchPredicate = SearchPredicate.And( something );

without ever mixing them. Is this safe/correct to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a `List` of it if you want to filter more? Instead return an `IQueryable` and then you can apply more filters on that... like this for example:

```
public IQueryable<Country> GetAllCountries()
{
    return from d in DTDC.Countries select d;
}
```

Then you can have extension methods for `IQueryable<Country>` like:

```
public static class CountryFilters
{
    public static IQueryable<Country> ThatContainsName(this IQueryable<Country> query, string country)
    {
        return query.Where(y => y.Name.ToLower().Contains(country.ToLower()));
    }
}
```

To that you can add more filters, and last when you have filtered your query you can make on that extracts your ids.

Also, when applying those filters I would check that the generated sql is of good quality so you don't end up making multiple queries.